# How do I select a random element from a 2d list

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists

I'm trying to select a random element in a  2D list in python. 
I'm creating a blackjack game.

> I'm aware of how long and non-optimized this code is, but I'm new to programming and I want to make mistakes to learn.
>
> Here's the initial code that I have set up. I create the suits (spades, clubs, hearts, diamonds). I append it to the list called list_of_cards which was initialized as an empty array.
>
> Then I have another list called player_card for the player to view. Here it is in reference.

```
list_of_suits= []       #Creating list of cards
player_card  = []

king_of_spades  =  10   #Creating face cards for the spades deck.
queen_of_spades =  10   
jack_of_spades  =  10

king_of_clubs  =  10   
queen_of_clubs =  10      
jack_of_clubs  =  10

king_of_hearts  =   10   
queen_of_hearts =   10    
jack_of_hearts  =   10

king_of_diamonds  =  10   
queen_of_diamonds =  10 
jack_of_diamonds  =  10

ace_of_spades =   [1,11]     # Aces are either 1 or 11
ace_of_clubs =    [1,11]
ace_of_hearts =   [1,11]
ace_of_diamonds = [1,11] 


spades = [ace_of_spades,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, jack_of_spades, queen_of_spades, king_of_spades]
clubs =  [ace_of_clubs,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, jack_of_clubs, queen_of_clubs, king_of_clubs]
hearts =  [ace_of_hearts,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, jack_of_hearts, queen_of_hearts, king_of_hearts]
diamonds =  [ace_of_diamonds,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, jack_of_diamonds, queen_of_diamonds, king_of_diamonds]

list_of_suits.append(spades)
list_of_suits.append(clubs)
list_of_suits.append(hearts)
list_of_suits.append(diamonds)
```

> This is the selector for a random card. It will iterate through the array to select one of the four cards randomly. Next, it will go into that array and choose a random card.

```
random_list_of_suits = random.choice(list_of_suits)

random_card_number = random.choice(random_list_of_suits)    
random_list_of_suits.remove(random_card_number)
player_card.append(random_card_number)

print player_card
print list_of_suits
```

> Here's what I'm trying to figure out: How do I create a new random number each time?
>
> I'm kind of stuck and I tried putting it through a for loop, but if I put the random_card_number in a loop, it will select the same random card that it did initially four times.

Comment: put `random.choice(list_of_suits)` in the loop,don't pass in a variable.

Comment: In a broader scope, wouldn't it be better if each card was self-descriptive, you could toss them all in one "deck" list, and just shuffle the deck and take a card off the top (by `pop`ing the list?) Consider doing something like `spades = [(ace_of_spades, 'spades'), (2, 'spades'), (3, 'spades') ...]` and etc for all the suits, then just tossing your deck together from that.

Comment: Obviously this could be approached with a greater degree of control if you're ready to jump into OOP, but I think that's the smallest change that will make the biggest impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

list2d = [range(0, 5), range(5, 10), range(10, 15), range(15, 20)]

for i in range(0, 10):
    random_suite = random.choice(list2d)
    random_card = random.choice(random_suite)
    print random_suite, random_card
```

output:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 7
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 5
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 5
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 11
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 13
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 12
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 14
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 10
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 10
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The list you enter in random.choice() must be a 1D array.
So you can do this,

```
random_list_of_suits = np.random.choice(list_of_suits) # you can get spades/clubs/hearts/diamonds
index_of_random_card_number = random.choice(len(random_list_of_suits))
random_card = random_list_of_suits[index_of_random_card_number] # You get a random card
```

Answer (score -5):

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // for rand() and srand()
#include <ctime> // for time()
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    srand(time(0)); // set initial seed value to system clock
    for (int nCount=0; nCount < 100; ++nCount)
    {
        cout << rand() << "\t";

        if ((nCount+1) % 5 == 0)
            cout << endl;
    }
```

The srand uses time as the first intial seed to create your random numbers therefore each time you run the program you will get a different random number because the intail seed will be changing with the time.

Comment: I think you might have posted this on the wrong question?

Comment: The answer needs to be in Python